# laravel 5.4 passport - authentication 3rd party login

Tags: laravel, api, login, oauth2, laravel-auth

Eu tenho este sistema que desenvolvi. Ele é desenvolvido em reactjs + redux + sagas no frontend e RESTFUL API no backend em laravel.

MAS na empresa na qual trabalho há a exigência de que o login seja centralizado e provido por um sistema próprio do departamento central de TI. Todos sistemas da empresa devem submeter-se a esta autenticação central.

Então eu consigo achar online muitos tutoriais que utilizam o Laravel Passport como servidor de autenticação para outros sistemas consumirem a API. No entanto o que eu preciso saber é como, a um só tempo, ter o meu backend sendo consumidor de outra API para autenticar os usuários e salvaguardas as rotas da minha API.

Seria algo como utilizar o facebook para login. Mas não é facebook é keycloak. Eu nem bem sei o que buscar na net para achar esta solução na verdade. Todos tutoriais que envolvem login com "3rd party" são sobre login do facebook ou google especificamente já com plugins e tudo o mais. eles não me ajudam pois não consigo adaptá-los ao meu problema.

alguém algures pode me ajudar?